# Is Nvidia's GEFORCE GTX 1650 suitable for scientific computing and simulation?

Tags: laptop, graphics-cards, high-end, mobile-workstation

I use LinuxMint OS, and work with Fortran, Python, and Openfoam for scientific computing and fluid dynamics simulation. I am buying a new laptop from ASUS that has GEFORCE GTX 1650 (4 GB) card (fits my budget). May I ask if this GPU card can be used for numerical computations and simulation that are not too intensive? I have limited experience with Quadro cards. Thank you for your help.